# Дождаться завершения процесса

Tags: c#

Я через свою программу запускаю дочерний процесс. Через некоторое время отработав он завершится. Мне надо поймать этот момент. Конечно я могу парсить все запущенные процессы и увидеть когда нужного процесса в списке не будет, но может кто подскажет более изящное решение?

Comment: Можно обернуть этот процесс своей обёрткой, которая просто вызовет необходимый метод, хэндлер по завершению процесса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Включите уведомление при завершении работы процесса и подпишитесь на `Exited`:

```
public void StartProcess(string fileName)
{  
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;    
  process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

  process.Exited += (sender, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine($"Процесс завершен с кодом {process.ExitCode}");
  }

  process.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: не работает(  `Process proc = new Process();  
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "wevtutil";
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " qe System /c:100 /rd:true /f:text > Security.log";
                    proc.Exited += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine($"Процесс завершен с кодом {proc.ExitCode}"); };

                    proc.Start();
                    Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: @polsok А где вы proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true дели?)

Comment: А теперь работает спасибо