# Проверка на активность процесса в системе в отдельном потоке (задача)

Tags: c#

Помогите составить правильный код, мне нужно решить задачу,есть бот (отдельная прога), которая запускается в 2 этапа. На первом этапе происходит скачивание файлов для работы этого бота, для этого дела первым запускается процесс `start.exe`, затем после завершения скачивания этот процесс завершается и запускается второй процесс под названием `FastExecuteScript`, который как раз таки и является основным процессом бота.

В общем, я хочу сделать такой метод в своей программе,который каждую секунду чекает есть ли в системе процесс `FastExecuteScript` и если его нету программа завершает свою работу, как мне сделать так, чтобы моя программа заранее не завершалась,потому что первым запускается процесс `start.exe` и лишь только после скачивания файлов запускается процесс `FastExecuteScript`

Код:

```cs
private static void CheckMainProcessOnActive()
{
    var processExists = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("start"));
    if (processExists == false)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var processExists2 = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("FastExecuteScript"));
        if (processExists2 == false)
        {
            DeleteHideDirectory();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так запускайте последовательно все, сначала `start.exe`, ждите его завершения (только до сих пор не пойму, почему это отдельный процесс), затем, как он завершит свою работу, ждите `FastExecuteScript`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дождаться завершения процесса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769576/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: Так я как раз таки и написал такой код,выше вы можете его увидеть,но он не работает,что я не так сделал?

Comment: Моя программа является запускатором этого бота а также защитой для него.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что вы написали то, что сказал вам я. Где, например запуск? Почему он отдельно от этого кода? И почему вы усыпляете поток? Если у вас это в UI потоке, то ваше приложение зависает на 5 сек. Ок, а перезапуск проверки где?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.Я сегодня вообще мало что-то соображаю.Завернул этот код в бесконечный while цикл и поток вызвал в самом конце после запуска основного процесса бота.